# Java throwing exception for "No line found" when attempting to gather input from Scanner object

Tags: java, exception

I am fairly new to Java and am attempting to build a "Top 10 Java Projects for Beginners" project, more specifically, a temperature converter. My code throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
        at TempConvert.convertToFar(TempConvert.java:78)
        at TempConvert.main(TempConvert.java:15)
```

I was originally using the scanner "*.nextDouble()" method to grab the double but changed it to the "parseDouble" method as I thought this was perhaps the issue. Alas, this has not helped. Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

```
    public static double convertToFar()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userEntry;
        double formula, userDouble;
        System.out.print("Enter degrees in Celsius: ");
        userEntry = in.nextLine();
        userDouble = Double.parseDouble(userEntry);
        in.close();
        formula = (userDouble - 32) * (5/9);
        return formula;
    }
```

Comment: @cliff2310 thanks. Edited my post for (hopefully) better clarity!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `in.nextLine()` in the methods you wrote eventually collided with the string that was inputted by the user before the input stream had been closed.
I created one Scanner object and sent it to the methods so that they will be able to use that same object. I close it only when the program ends once the user enters 'E'. It worked for me:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TempConvert {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    
        double far, cel;
        char userChoice;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  // I added this line
        userChoice = displayMenu(in);
        while (userChoice != 'E')
        {
            if (userChoice == 'F')
            {
                far = convertToFar(in);
                System.out.println("Converted: " + far + "\u00B0");
                userChoice = displayMenu(in);
            }
            else if (userChoice == 'C')
            {
                cel = convertToCel(in);
                System.out.println("Converted: " + cel + "\u00B0");
                userChoice = displayMenu(in);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
                userChoice = displayMenu(in);
            }
        }
        in.close();  // closing the input stream when the program ends
    
    
    }

    public static void displayTitle()
    {
        String title = "||---- TEMPERATURE CONVERTER ----||";
        String one = "-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-";
        String two = "||       ** Auth: Arranic        ||";
        String three = "||                               ||";

        System.out.println(one + "\n" + three + "\n" + title + "\n" + three     + "\n" + two + "\n" + three + "\n" + one);
    }

    public static char displayMenu(Scanner input)
    {
        ClearScreen();
        displayTitle();

        System.out.println("\n");

        String choiceString;
        char choice;
    
        System.out.println("F - FARENHEIGHT      C - CELSIUS      E - EXIT");
        System.out.print("CONVERT TO: ");
        choiceString = input.nextLine();
        // input.close()   --> removed this line
        choice = Character.toUpperCase(choiceString.charAt(0));

        return choice;
    }

    public static void ClearScreen()
    {
        System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
        System.out.flush();
    }

    public static double convertToCel(Scanner in)
    {
        String userEntry;
        double formula, userDouble;
        System.out.print("Enter degrees in Fahrenheit: ");
        userEntry = in.nextLine();
        // in.close()   --> removed this line
        userDouble = Double.parseDouble(userEntry);
        formula = (userDouble - 32) * (5.0/9);
        return formula;
    }

    public static double convertToFar(Scanner in)
    {
        String userEntry;
        double userDouble, formula;
        System.out.print("Enter degrees in Celsius: ");
        userEntry = in.nextLine();
        // in.close()   --> removed this line
        userDouble = Double.parseDouble(userEntry);
        formula = (userDouble * (9.0/5)) + 32;
        return formula;
    }
}
```

BTW your calculations are not precise. You should remember that integer/integer = integer. That said, writing 5/9 or 9/5 is not accurate, since the result is an integer type number, and not a double type number, as I assume you wanted to get. (5/9 = 0, 9/5 = 1) So you should have added a 5.0 or 9.0 to the calculations so that Java would understand that you want to get a double type result (double/int = double).
And one more thing, your calculations where misplaced (fahrenheit to celsius gave me the opposite result and vice versa) so I switched them up ;).